# Eclipse JUnit @Before annotation problem

Tags: junit

I'm experiencing some difficulties using JUnit 4.5 in Eclipse, when I use @Before annotation it just does nothing (I may use setUp() which works of course, but I'm just wondering what is wrong), while it works perfectly in Netbeans.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Post an example test so we can have a look

Comment: Are you extending TestCase?  If so I think it ignores annotations.

Comment: did you specify the good jar for your project?

Comment: Thank you Pace, I've overlooked that Eclipse extends TestCase automatically, thank you once again.

Answer (score 6):

Because I cam here via a Google Search, and had to dig quite a bit deeper to see the actual solution:
As @Pace said in the comments, if you `extend TestCase`, Eclipse treats the Test as JUnit Version 3 or older, and does not respect the `@Before` annotation - also descripred here: [JUnit + Maven + Eclipse: Why @BeforeClass does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274573/junit-maven-eclipse-why-beforeclass-does-not-work)

Hence, removing the `extend TestCase` causes fixes the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JUnit 4, you can just annotate the test class or the test method with @Test annotation, instead of extending TestCase.

Comment: He's asking about the @Before annotation, he doesn't say anything about tests that fail to run.

Comment: Even though this is correct this does not address the question OP has asked.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using JUnit 4+ there are two ways to write a test case

1 > You make your test class `extend TestCase`. In this case classes corresponding to Junit 3 are picked up which are not aware of `@Before` annotation. In this case you will have to override

```
/**
 * Sets up the fixture, for example, open a network connection.
 * This method is called before a test is executed.
 */
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
}
```

2 > use annotations. use `@Test` annotation for the method in the test class that you are interested in running as a test. There is no need for your class to `extend TestCase`. Also you do not have to override any method. Simply define your own method that has the logic to be executed before the test method runs and annotate it with `@Before` annotation.