# JUnit + Maven + Eclipse: Why @BeforeClass does not work?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am using JUnit 4, Maven 2 and latest Eclipse. Problem is simple: I would like to perform some setup (connecting to a database) before my tests are executed.

I tried @BeforeClass in many different locations but Eclipse and Maven are ignoring this. Any help on accomplishing this initial setup?

Thanks!

```
public abstract class BaseTestCase extends TestCase {

 @BeforeClass
    public static void doBeforeClass() throws Exception {

   System.out.println("No good @BeforeClass");

   // DO THE DATABASE SETUP

    }
}
```

Now the tests extending BaseTestCase:

```
public class LoginActionTest extends BaseTestCase {

 @Test
 public void testNothing() {

  System.out.println("TEST HERE");

  assertEquals(true, true);
 }
}
```

Maven and Eclipse just ignore my @BeforeClass ??? Any other way to perform setup before tests?

Comment: Can you please confirm how you launch your test case from within Eclipse? Are you using the JUnit4?

Comment: I am using JUnit 4. I am launching with Run As... -> JUnit Test... The problem is related to extending TestCase. If you give up extending that class then you are fine. You actually don't need this class as you can import the Assert class to perform the checking... Don't extend TestCase and everything works as expected...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sergio, you were right about extending TestCase causing the problem. If you extend TestCase, JUnit treats your test class as an old (pre JUnit 4 class) and picks `org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner` to run it. JUnit38ClassRunner does not know about `@BeforeClass` annotation. Check out source code of `runnerForClass` method of `AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder` and `runnerForClass` method of `JUnit3Builder` for more details.

Note: This problem is not related to Eclipse or Maven.

Comment: Yeah. I gave up extending TestCase and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are running with JUnit 3. Try renaming your test to something which does not start with "test". If the test is no longer executing, you are using JUnit 3 (which assumes that test methods are methods which starts with "test").

Please post your Eclipse launch config.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem and I fixed it by specifying surefile and junit versions explisitly:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More info is here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

It seems junit 3.8.1 version is used transiently through maven-resources-plugin and plexus-container-default. You can print dependency tree by calling **mvn dependency:tree**. I think there's no other way to make surefire use junit 4.